# user_id not being set in the access_token table in FOSOAuthBundle

Tags: php, symfony, oauth, fosoauthserverbundle

I'm using FOSOAuthBundle with FOSUserBundle for an API which is used by mobile apps etc. I'm trying to access some user profile information using the access token to find the users details, however the user_id isn't being set.

```
<?php

namespace MyBundle\ApiBundle\Entity;

use FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Entity\AccessToken as BaseAccessToken;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class AccessToken extends BaseAccessToken
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    protected $client;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MyBundle\UserBundle\Entity\User")
     */
    protected $user;
}
```

Further info, I was following the tutorial in your documentation. Here's my security:

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_USER:        ROLE_USER
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_ADMIN
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true
        oauth_token:
            pattern:    ^/oauth/v2/token
            security:   false

        oauth_authorize:
            pattern:    ^/oauth/v2/auth
            security: true
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                check_path: /oauth/v2/auth/login_check
                login_path: /oauth/v2/auth/login

        api:
            pattern:    ^/api
            fos_oauth:  true
            stateless:  true
            anonymous:  false # can be omitted as its default value

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/api$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
        - { path: ^/checkout$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Here's my config settings for UserBundle and oAuthBundle:

```
# app/config/config.yml
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: PremierParkingLogistics\UserBundle\Entity\User

# app/config/config.yml
fos_oauth_server:
    db_driver: orm       # Driver availables: orm, mongodb, or propel
    client_class:        PremierParkingLogistics\ApiBundle\Entity\Client
    access_token_class:  PremierParkingLogistics\ApiBundle\Entity\AccessToken
    refresh_token_class: PremierParkingLogistics\ApiBundle\Entity\RefreshToken
    auth_code_class:     PremierParkingLogistics\ApiBundle\Entity\AuthCode
    service:
        user_provider: fos_user.user_manager
```

I was following this guide: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md

Any help or point in the right direction, would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you set grant_type to password when requesting token.

Comment: What if I want to use another grant type? like `client_credentials`?